# Searching in data set and return values based on some criteria with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to look through my data set and find all values that meet the certain conditions. I have tried `pandas.where(cond)` which just accept one condition.

For example consider the following data set:

```
a    b    c     d

1    2    3     899

4    5    -344  21

7    8      9   10
```

I need this result: `0< data.values and data.values <30`

```
a    b    c      d

1    2    3      Nan

4    5     Nan   21

7    8      9   10
```

Most of the scripts return the rows or columns that meet the conditions.
However I need the rest of the value in each column and row. For example I do not want to lose 2 and 3 in row first and 4 and 5 in row second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `boolean DataFrame` and apply [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with `'invert conditions'` - `<` to `>=` and `>` to `<=`:

```
m = (df >= 0) & (df <= 30)
print (m)
      a     b      c      d
0  True  True   True  False
1  True  True  False   True
2  True  True   True   True

df = df[m]
#alternatively
#df = df.where(m)
print (df)
   a  b    c     d
0  1  2  3.0   NaN
1  4  5  NaN  21.0
2  7  8  9.0  10.0
```

Numpy solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, df, np.nan), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
     a    b    c     d
0  1.0  2.0  3.0   NaN
1  4.0  5.0  NaN  21.0
2  7.0  8.0  9.0  10.0
```

Or use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m = (df < 0) | (df > 30)
df = df.mask(m)
print (df)

   a  b    c     d
0  1  2  3.0   NaN
1  4  5  NaN  21.0
2  7  8  9.0  10.0
```

Comment: Is there any way to mask the columns like above by specific conditions? I mean that, for every column check the certain condition and update that column and so..

Comment: I would like to help, but now I am going to bed. So the best is create new question with sample data, desired output and some code, what you try. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with a binary expression (which can be compound) as the selection criteria. Pandas overloads the dunder (double underscore) function for array subscripting to take a binary expression.  A common problem in using this is that it is *not* a logical expression, so you need to use bit wise operators `&` and `|` in the expression when it is compound. These operators bind tighter than equality and comparison operators (e.g. `==`, `>`, `>=`) so you need to put your comparisons inside parentheses.

I believe the answer given by @jezrael will work.  This is just an explanation of what s/he has provided.